# Django view visible only to admin

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a view in my django backend which I want only admin to see.

```
@api_view(('GET',))
def get_analytics(request):
# Number of users who dogged in once to our system today
login_count= User.objects.filter(last_login__startswith=timezone.now().date()).count()


data = {}
data['login_count'] = login_count

return JSONResponse(data)
```

It's a function based view. How can I make it visible only to admin? it's corresponding url I hit from my angular app to get and render the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the below decorator

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required

@staff_member_required
```

Answer (score 2):

You can **add [`IsAdminUser`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#isadminuser) permission class** to your view to restrict access to only admin users. Only users with admin permissions will be granted access then. Others will be denied access.

```
@api_view(('GET',))
@permission_classes((IsAdminUser, )) # add the permission class
def get_analytics(request):
    ...
    return JSONResponse(data)
```

When the permissions fail, then either an `exceptions.PermissionDenied` or `exceptions.NotAuthenticated` exception will be raised depending on [some conditions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#how-permissions-are-determined).